Vue 3 upgrade props are passed but not show in the component
I have following Vue 3 component image-template-row-item which has the prop templates-types

which is defined in the component in the props:

now this prop is always passed as undefined to the component while appears in the attrs:


so what am i missing here to make it work?

Please enter code into your question, instead of screenshots.

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Props are usually normalized under the hood, camel-cased and kebab-cased props are mutually interchangeable. This doesn't apply to any random case.
It should be permissionsRoot but not PermissionsRoot, and so on.

maybe if you try to define it as an object and changing the first uppercase letter to lowercase
props: {
    item: String,
    templatesTypes: String,
    permissionsRoot: String,
    index: String,

},

